# grant my app permission through adb shell command

Tags: android, adb

In Android SDK, I know I can use `adb shell` to grant my app location access permission by command:

```
adb shell pm grant com.xyz.myapp android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

Now, my app also needs VPN permission like this one:
[image]

How can I grant my app VPN connection permission the same way as how I did for location permission with `adb` command?

Comment: are you talking about **android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE** permission ?

Comment: @NishantPardamwar, maybe, I am not sure about the permission string for the dialog I am showing in my question, that's why I ask here

Comment: I dont think this will work, but have you tried `adb shell pm grant com.xyz.myapp android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE` ?

Answer (score 3):

The permission you require is `android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE`, and this permission has `signature` protection level. It can only be acquired by system application.

The dialog popup in you picture is not an usual permission grant dialog.

It's created by the following code, a `Intent` to system activity.

```
Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(v.getContext());
if (intent != null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
} else {
    onActivityResult(RESULT_OK, 0, null);
}
```

More information, see the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html#prepare(android.content.Context)).